# How to pass a value instead of the Index (Not too familiar with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I feel that this is a very simple answer. I found a nice script below and I just want to change what is passed to the textbox from the dropdown list. Currently if United States is selected, United States is passed to the textbox. However, the value for United States is "us". I'd like "us" to be passed to the textbox. What needs to be adjusted to make this work? Thank you in advance!

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "txt"+rowCount;
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
            }
            }
        }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
        }
    }
    function addVal(obj,ob){
        var suf = ob.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt'+suf);
        txt.value = obj;
    }
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
    <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" id="txt0" name="txt"/></TD>
    <TD>
    <SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML,this)">
    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML,this)">
```

to

```
<SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this.value,this)">
```

**Edit for your follow up question**
You current script is tailored specifically for the table you are working with. So much that it has the childNode index hardcoded to 0 `newcell.childNodes[0].value`. You have to understand there is correlation between the function `addRow` and the content of your table.

I made some quick and simple changes to the table and function so that it would allow for more than 1 control per table cell, **though you'll need to change it to your flavor so it does what *you* need it to do**.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        for(var a = 0; a < newcell.childNodes.length; a++)
        {
            switch(newcell.childNodes[a].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[a].value = "";
            newcell.childNodes[a].id = newcell.childNodes[a].name + rowCount;
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[a].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[a].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
            }
        }

    }
}
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if(rowCount <= 1) {
        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
        break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
        }
        }
    }catch(e) {
    alert(e);
    }
}
function addVal(obj,ob){
    var suf = ob.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var txt = document.getElementById('txt'+suf);
    txt.value = obj;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
<TR>
<TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
<TD><INPUT type="text" id="txt0" name="txt"/><input type="text" id="addedTxt0" name="addedTxt"/></TD>
<TD>
<SELECT name="country" onchange="addVal(this.value,this)">
<OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
<OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
<OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
<OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
<OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I have an add-on question to this that I hope you can help me with. When I click the "Add Row" button, it clearly adds an additional row. Well, I added another text box with a datepicker (to select a calendar date). However, it only works on the first row. Once I click add, it wont work on any subsequent rows. I'm using a basic script (see below). I feel that somewhere after "function addRow(tableID)" is where I need to somehow increment the id for the new textbox - Hope that made sense.

Comment: <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dtd1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  } );
  </script> HTML: <input type="text" name="ExpectedDate[]" size="10" id="dtd1">